# Learning Math with Mathematica

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Are there any books/online courses that use Mathematica (or other software) to teach mathematical concepts? I find learning more advanced concepts a lot easier when I am exploring the concepts interactively.

Answer (score 1):

See for instance [Modern Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces with Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/books/profile.cgi?id=6280).

Comment: Awesome. That is very much in-line with what I'm looking for